# How to get products list with details by category_id from rest api of magento 2.0?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

https://www.example.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories/[category_id]/products
it is only returning me a list of SKU.
I need all products with details by categry_id

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a request to this URL and it should work:

[`http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=<category_id_here>&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1`](http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=%3Ccategory_id_here%3E&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but its not the answer exactly i want. i need {
    "id": 52,
    "sku": "CN-101",
    "name": " JBnB Pro Series Crown Soccer Ball Size 5",
    "attribute_set_id": 11,
    "price": 990,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    ]

Comment: your query is  {
    "items": [],
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "category_id",
                        "value": "<40>",
                        "condition_type": "eq"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "sort_orders": [
            {
                "field": "created_at",
                "direction": "DESC"
            }
        ],
        "page_size": 10,
        "current_page": 2
    },
    "total_count": 0
}